# Unhandled Exception: type 'FlutterError' is not a subtype of type 'Exception' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I am trying to redirect a user to Home screen after a successful login using Flutter, but I end up getting the error, and back to login page not being redirected.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'FlutterError' is not a subtype of type
> 'Exception' in type cast

What I have done so far

my signin Function

```
handleSignIn() async {
    await msal.signIn(null, [SCOPE]).then((result) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Home()));
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        final ex = exception as Exception;
        print('exception occurred');
        print(ex.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Updating the signed in state

```
  refreshSignedInStatus() {
    msal.getSignedIn().then((loggedIn) {
      print('refreshing');
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = loggedIn;
      });
    });
  }
```

Handling the onclick on the button

```
 Text(' Sign in', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onPressed: handleSignIn,
                        ),
                      )),
```

What am I doing wrong, Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need TypeCasting here

`final ex = exception as Exception;`
This syntax causes an error

you can simply assign the exception to a variable(not recommended) or you can directly use that variable(recommended).

Comment: Am I placing my Navigator on the right place as it is not being called after a successful authentication?

Comment: return Future<dynamic> and compare the response. if the response is not null then navigate otherwise show the toast.

Comment: I have a snippet of API calls which you can refer https://pastebin.com/GpxvWsCk.